# MySQL extract number placed before and after a specific word

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a MySQL table "products" with a descriptions field which contains the word "pack" or "pack of":

```
Headphones 3 pack, Built-in Microphone - (Latest Model)
Wireless headphones -Bluetooth Headphones 3.5 -3 Pack
Flash Drive-128G-B35 -(12pack)
Wireless headphones -Bluetooth Headphones -(11- pack) Latest Model
Wireless headphones -Bluetooth Headphones -(Pack of 11)
Wireless headphones -Bluetooth Headphones -(packs of 11)
```

I need a regular expression to extract the number before word "pack" and after words "pack of" ,

The output should be :

```
3
3
12
11
11
11
```

Tried a lot of combinations for the regular expression

```
    SELECT @str:="Headphones 3 pack, Built-in Microphone - (Latest Model)" AS str,
                   regexp_replace(@str, '[^0-9]*(pack)', '')+0 AS packof;
```

This one works for number in front of words "pack of" still not sure if it covers all scenarios:

```
SELECT @str:="Wireless headphones -Bluetooth Headphones -(Pack of 11)" AS str,
               regexp_replace(@str, '.*pack[^0-9]*', '')+0 AS packof;
```

Comment: seems like a job for regexp_substr, not regexp_replace?

Comment: Some things are better done in the application, not SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
regexp_replace(@str, '(?i)^.*?(?:packs?(?:\\W+of)?\\W*(\\d+)|(\\d+)\\W*pack).*', '$1$2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yRC5wo/2). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:packs?(?:\W+of)?\W*(\d+)|(\d+)\W*pack)` - either of:

  - `packs?(?:\W+of)?\W*(\d+)` - `pack`, an optional `s`, an optional sequence of one or more non-word chars and then `of` word, zero or more non-word chars, and one or more digits captured into Group 1
  - `|` - or
  - `(\d+)\W*pack` - one or more digits captured into Group 2, zero or more non-word chars, and then a `pack` string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The `$1$2` replacement replaces the match with Group 1 + Group 2 values.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have tried the regex. but with no success. Tried online on following platform https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xpkmttfp , and also on my local Mysql server 8.0.20 same result!

Comment: @sorin The regex is correct, I just forgot to double the backslashes in the MySQL code.